sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can
I'm trying to make a connection with MySQL DB using Python but I'm getting this error no matter what I do. I allready changed my localhost to 127.0.0.1.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

class DbConnectionHandler:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__connection_string = 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/clean_database'

        self.__engine = self.__create_data_base_engine()
        self.session = None
        
    def __create_data_base_engine(self):
        engine = create_engine(self.__connection_string)
        return engine
    
    def get_engine(self):
        return self.__engine
    
    def __enter__(self):
        session_make = sessionmaker(bind=self.__engine)
        self.session = session_make()
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session.close()

And I got this error all the time:
E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
E   (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
ERROR src/infra/db/repositories/users_repository_test.py - sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can...
Some good soul can please help me? Thank you guys.

are you sure that mysql is installed and configured in your computer, see if you fund the mysql error log, and see if something is wrong#

yes I do. I'm using DBeaver and MySQLWorkbench. Both are open and installed. I'm just not importing mysql on project because I'm using mysql+pymysql type.

This error normally means that the port is not open for you. Could be a firewall or the mysql service is not running on your machine (localhost). Unless you confirm that DBeaver or MySQLWorkbench can connect to the DB. Then double check the settings in those applications.

@Kate I tested connection on both DBeaver and MySQLWorkbench but I have no idea how to solve the firewall trouble you quote. But that's a nice point. Thank you!

And so you did try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? I am not sure about which OS you use but it is conceivable that for example localhost is resolving to a socket or even an IPv6 address, on which no Mysql process is listening. See this note as well.

@Kate I'm using Windows, but I'm running my projects on Linux by WSL. Could that be a problem? I'll see this note you quote. Thank you so much!!!

I am not familiar with WSL but indeed this is important information. I suppose it works like a container and may have its own IP addresses. Perhaps this thread can help.
